# tensorflow determinism probe (aka debug tool)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, non-deterministic

I'd like to use the debug probe mentioned [here](https://youtu.be/TB07_mUMt0U?t=679) but if I try to import the module as shown in the talk I get a syntax error as follows:

```
from tensorflow-determinism import probe
  File "<ipython-input-13-e6323193779e>", line 1
    from tensorflow-determinism import probe
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can't find anything in [the repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/framework-determinism) about it. I'm using TF 2.1.0 and tensorflow-determinism 0.3.0.

What is the cause of this error? or is there a different way I should be accessing the probe?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-determinism/): "This will install a package that can be imported as `tfdeterminism`.". So just use `from tfdeterminism import probe`. But `probe` is right now not available in this module and it's not known when will it be available (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/framework-determinism/issues/1)).